# Почему возникает ошибка webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

**Ошибка возникает при подключении картинки через img в html. При подключении через background, все работает.**

**Ошибка:**

```
ERROR in   Error: C:\Users\wsss\Desktop\webpack-main\src/index.html?../node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js:9
  var ___HTML_LOADER_IMPORT_0___ = new URL(/* asset import */ __webpack_require__(/*! ./img/img.jpg */ "./img/img.jpg"), __webpack_require__.b);
                                   ^
  ReferenceError: URL is not defined

  - loader.js:9 eval
    [index.html?..]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/loader.js:9:34

  - index.html:40 Object.../node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./index.html
    C:/Users/wsss/Desktop/webpack-main/src/index.html:40:1

  - index.html:73 __webpack_require__
    C:/Users/wsss/Desktop/webpack-main/src/index.html:73:41

  - index.html:131
    C:/Users/wsss/Desktop/webpack-main/src/index.html:131:37

  - index.html:134
    C:/Users/wsss/Desktop/webpack-main/src/index.html:134:12

  - node:vm:143 Script.runInContext
    node:vm:143:18

  - index.js:136 HtmlWebpackPlugin.evaluateCompilationResult
    [webpack-main]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:136:28

  - index.js:333
    [webpack-main]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:333:26

  - async Promise.all

  - async Promise.all



webpack 5.23.0 compiled with 1 error in 610 ms
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webpack-main@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --mode development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the webpack-main@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\wsss\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-18T23_54_12_036Z-debug.log
```

**файл webpack.config**

```
   const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
// const { Template } = require('webpack');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
const isProd = !isDev;

const filename = ext => isDev ? `[name].${ext}` : `[name].[contenthash].${ext}`
module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname,'src'),
    mode: 'development',
  entry: {
      main: './index.js',
      analytics: './analytics.js',
      bundle: [
        "webpack/hot/dev-server",
        (`${__dirname}/src/index.js`)
      ]
  },
    
  output: {
    filename: `./js/${filename('js')}`,
    path: path.resolve(__dirname,path.basename(__dirname)),
    // publicPath: '',
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, path.basename(__dirname)),
    open: true,
    compress: true,
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
  plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.html'),
        filename: 'index.html',
        minify: {
          collapseWhitespace: isProd
        }
      }),
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          filename: `./styles/${filename('css')}`,
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets') , to: path.resolve(__dirname, path.basename(__dirname))}
        ]
      }),
  ],
  module: {
      rules: [
          {
              test: /\.html$/,
              loader: 'html-loader'
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/i,
             use: [
                {
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    options: {
                      hmr: isDev
                    },
                  },
                  'css-loader'
              ],
          },
          {
            test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    options: {
                      publicPath: (resourcePath, context) => {
                        return path.relative(path.dirname(resourcePath), context) + '/';
                      },
                    }
                  },
                  'css-loader',
                  'sass-loader'
            ]
          },
          {
            test: /\.(?:|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/,
            use: [{
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                name: `./img/${filename('[ext]')}`
              }
            }],
          },
      ]
  }
}
```

**файл package.json**

```
   {
  "name": "webpack-main",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "test",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --mode development",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack serve --mode development"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "webpack",
    "js"
  ],
  "author": "Kochanov Andrei",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^7.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.8",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.23.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>aaaa</title>

</head> 
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Webpack</h1>
        <div class="wrapper__block"></div>
<img src="img/img.jpg" alt="d">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решено!

```
 {
      test: /\.html$/,
      loader: 'html-loader',
      options: {
      esModule: false
    }
  },
```